# Writing Data using RESTful web services through Android

Tags: java, android, post

i am developing android application.our java developer team write restfull web services for 
reading and writing data.i sucessfully read data and display into device.i used following android code to inserting data but it is not working.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

    ProgressDialog pd;
    List<NameValuePair>list;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new Mytask().execute();   
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public class Mytask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
    {


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inser Record Succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            pd.dismiss(); 

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pd.setMessage("Please Wait");
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            pushdata();
            return null;

        }

    }
    public void pushdata()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post=new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.239:8080/KesariRating/rating/add");
            // add data to url
            list=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
            list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("exce","e"));
            list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vgood","null"));
            list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("good","null"));
            list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("poor","null"));
            list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fair","null"));
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(list));
            HttpResponse response=client.execute(post);
            HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("Error in Push","",e);

        }
    }
}
```

could you told me what i did wrong in that code.i think we need to create class object and send to it then it will work. so how to create class object in above code and send to it.i also sending full source code of  web service. here is controller

```
public class RatingController 
{


    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value="/hello/{name}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public static String sayhello(@PathVariable String name)
    {   
        return "Hello "+name ;
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value="/sayhello/{name}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public static String add(@PathVariable String name)
    {   
    RatingCore ratingCore = new RatingCore();
    ratingCore.setExcellent("t");
    ratingCore.setVgood("t");

        RatingOperation.addRating(ratingCore);
        return "Hello "+name ;
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value="/add",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public static boolean add(@RequestBody RatingCore objRatingCore)
    {   

        return RatingOperation.addRating(objRatingCore);      

    }
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value="/getcount",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public static RatingCore getCount()
    {   

        return RatingOperation.getCount();    

    }

}
```

here is java code

```
public class RatingCore {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String excellent;
    private String vgood;
    private String good;
    private String poor;
    private String fair;
    private Date timestamp;

    public RatingCore() {

    }

    public RatingCore(int id, String excellent, String vgood, String good,

    String poor, String fair, Timestamp timestamp) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.excellent = excellent;
        this.vgood = vgood;
        this.good = good;
        this.poor = poor;
        this.fair = fair;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getExcellent() {
        return excellent;
    }

    public void setExcellent(String excellent) {
        this.excellent = excellent;
    }

    public String getVgood() {
        return vgood;
    }

    public void setVgood(String vgood) {
        this.vgood = vgood;
    }

    public String getGood() {
        return good;
    }

    public void setGood(String good) {
        this.good = good;
    }

    public String getPoor() {
        return poor;
    }

    public void setPoor(String poor) {
        this.poor = poor;
    }

    public String getFair() {
        return fair;
    }

    public void setFair(String fair) {
        this.fair = fair;
    }

    public Date getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is not working? any errors or exceptions?

Comment: Record is not inserted into table .

Comment: i want to know to that how to create object of class and sent with post method in android

Comment: please help i am stuck in problem. i am not going further in my application

Answer (score 0):

Its my code for Sending some data to Server database,I hope It will help You

```
    private void validat_user(String stg1, String stg2,String stg3, String stg4,String stg5, String stg6,String stg7, String stg8,String stg9, String stg10,String stg11)
    {

        WebServiceTask wst = new WebServiceTask(WebServiceTask.POST_TASK, this, "Authentication in progress...");

        wst.addNameValuePair("A_ID", stg1);
        wst.addNameValuePair("A_NAME", stg2);
        wst.addNameValuePair("A_PWD1", stg3);
        wst.addNameValuePair("A_JOIN", stg4);
        wst.addNameValuePair("A_END", stg5);
        wst.addNameValuePair("A_COURSE", stg6);
        wst.addNameValuePair("A_FACID", stg7);
        wst.addNameValuePair("A_SESSION", stg8);
        wst.addNameValuePair("A_BATCH", stg9);
        wst.addNameValuePair("A_BRANCH1", stg10);
        wst.addNameValuePair("A_GENDER", stg11);
        wst.execute(new String[] { SERVICE_URL });

    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void no_net()
    {
        display( "No Network Connection");
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Staff.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("No Internet Connection");
        alertDialog.setMessage("You don't have internet connection.\nElse please check the Internet Connection Settings.");
        //alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.error_info);
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialog.setButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {   
                alertDialog.cancel();
                Staff.this.finish();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setButton2("Use Local DataBase", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                display( "Accessing local DataBase.....");
                alertDialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    private class WebServiceTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        public static final int POST_TASK = 1;

        private static final String TAG = "WebServiceTask";

        // connection timeout, in milliseconds (waiting to connect)
        private static final int CONN_TIMEOUT = 3000;

        // socket timeout, in milliseconds (waiting for data)
        private static final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 5000;

        private int taskType = POST_TASK;
        private Context mContext = null;
        private String processMessage = "Processing...";

        private ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        private ProgressDialog pDlg = null;

        public WebServiceTask(int taskType, Context mContext, String processMessage) {

            this.taskType = taskType;
            this.mContext = mContext;
            this.processMessage = processMessage;
        }

        public void addNameValuePair(String name, String value) {

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
        }
```